# Brush tool missing

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am quite new in using Blender 2.78 so please understand if this is an absurd question.

I was sculpting a model in Blender (using Crease tool) then after I've exited and re-opened the project,
Crease tool and Brush tool are missing!

How can I restore them?

[image]

[image]

I have created a new blender file then opened the old file > append > brush but I still don't see the brushes I need.

Comment: Probably you have unlinked the crease brush (shift+click on the x icon near the brush). To get it back, use another saved Blender file (a new one from scratch). Now from the file where the brush is missing, use file/append, go into the previously saved file, then in 'brush' and choose the 'crease' brush.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @lemon said you may have *unlinked your brush* with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd>.
[image]

After saving, closing and opening .blend file the brush is not there. Press the ***'+'*** button next to the brush's name, then go to *Brush*-->*Sculpt Tool* and select the type of brush you want. Rename the brush and it's ready to go.
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to find the brush tool! :D

Comment: Glad to hear that :). One more thing- press the little **F** window next to the newly created brush's name to make it a fake user.