# Deleted Smooth Brush

Tags: edit-mode, sculpting

I managed to somehow completely delete the Smooth brush in Blender. I've tried closing and opening the project, uninstalling and re-installing the app...nothing!
Thanks in advance :)
PS: if you know how to delete that repeated brush, that would be awesome as well!
[image]

Comment: I don't really think you should reinstall the app just to retrieve back the brush, try opening that Brush.004 you want to delete, then navigate to 3d viewport footer > Brush > Sculpt Tool > Smooth. If doesn't work save the user preferences backup, then reset to Factory settings, save as startup and in new project append brush from the file you reset

Comment: This question was very well answered by Paul Gonet:
[https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77497/brush-tool-missing][1]